# how to send <!--more--> for blogger API?

Tags: php, blogger

anyone know how to send `<!--more-->` when create post using blogger API?
i use this xml https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol#CreatingPublicEntries for create post, but when i write post with `<!--break-->` blogger eliminate this tag...

but when using Zend_Gdata, i successfully send `<!--more-->`

Answer (score 0):

This is wild speculation, but maybe if the *less than* were escaped, the XML comment sanitizer would not strip it out:

```
&lt;--more-->
```

Comment: thanks, but its does not work, i need `<!--more-->` is for insert line-break for blogger the post.

Answer (score 0):

The blogger API spits back

```
<a name="more"></a>
```

You should try inserting that if you can insert the  script it's asking for. I can't test this, just offering a suggestion.